Plotly Express Scatter plot hover data not holding its formatting
I take this dataset and preformat the columns numerically to represent currency and thousands commas.  Printing the dataset shows the formatted numbers. But when I use the data in a scatter plot and set the hover data, the formatting is stripped.  First the code:
    scatter_df["cost"] = "$" + scatter_df["cost"].apply(lambda x: "{:,.2f}".format(x))
    scatter_df["LRC"] = "$" + scatter_df["LRC"].apply(lambda x: "{:,.2f}".format(x))
    scatter_df["LR"] = scatter_df["LR"].apply(lambda x: "{:,}".format(x))
    print(scatter_df)
    fig = px.scatter(
        scatter_df,
        x="LR",
        y="LRC",
        color="country",
        title="Reach to Cost",
        hover_data={
            "cost": True,
        },
    )

And here is the data:



country
cost
LRC
LR.




Afghanistan
$2,665.70
$0.23
11,746


Azerbaijan
$6,172.40
$4.31
1,433


Brazil.
$7,084.11
$0.44
16,083


Georgia
$4,311.19
$1.14
3,795



And here is a photo of the hover:

The LR lost its comma, and the LRC lost the $.  Not even the AI's have been able to answer why or how to fix.

I ran your data and code and could not confirm the phenomenon you noted. What version of plotly are you currently using? I am using the latest version 5.22.0.

I will share the graphs I obtained.

My plotly version is 5.21.0

Don't preformat the data, just specify the d3-format for the ticks using tickformat. You can also set the formatting for a given column in hover_data :
scatter_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'country': ['Afghanistan', 'Azerbaijan', 'Brazil', 'Georgia'],
    'cost': [2665.70, 6172.40, 7084.11, 4311.19],
    'LRC': [0.23, 4.31, 0.44, 1.14],
    'LR': [11746, 1433, 16083, 3795],
})

fig = px.scatter(
    scatter_df,
    x="LR",
    y="LRC",
    color="country",
    title="Reach to Cost",
    hover_data={
        "cost": ':$,.2f'
    }
)

fig.update_layout(xaxis_tickformat=',', yaxis_tickformat='$,.2f')

fig.show()



Thank you.  I tried d3-format first in a hover-template and it didn't work, which is why I tried to force it in the dataframe.  This worked and appreciate the axis tip too!
    hover_data={
        "cost": ":$,.2f",
        "LRC": ":$,.2f",
        "LR": ":,",
    },

